# When the user chooses a radio button, a picture shows up for the chosen letter and a sound file plays

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an app that deals with the letters A-D. When a Radio Button from the Radio Group is chosen, that button is suppose to show a picture and make a sound. I am having trouble with my sounds. My raw file is not recognizing and I'm not sure where my MediaPlayer is suppose to go within the code. I must use OnCheckedChangeListener

```
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.*;
 import android.RadioGroup.*;

 **public class** MainActivity **extends** ActionBarActivity **implements** OnCheckedChangeListener{

 RadioGroup ABCDRadioGroup;
 ImageView LetterImageView;

 **protected void** onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.*activity_main*);

 ABCDRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.*AlphabetRadioGroup*);
 LetterImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.*LetterImageView*);
 ABCDRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(**this**);

 }

 @Override
 **public boolean** onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.*main*, menu);
 **return true;**

 }

 @Override 
 **public boolean** onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 **int** id = item.getItem();
 **if** (id == R.id.action_settings) {
     **return true;**
 }
 **return super**.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 **public void** onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
 }
 **public void** onClick(View v){
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(**this**, R.raw.A);
 mp.start();
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(**this**, R.raw.B);
 mp start();
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(**this**, R.raw.C);
 mp.start();
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(**this**, R.raw.D);
 mp start();
 }

 @override
 **public void** onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int arg1) {
 **if** (arg1 == R.id.LetterARadioButton)
 {
   LetterImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lettera);
 }
 **else if**(arg1 == R.id.BRadioButton)
 {
   LetterImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.letterb);
 }
 **else if**(arg1 == R.id.CRadioButton)
 {
   LetterImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.letterc);
 }
 **else if**(arg1 == R.id.DRadioButton)
 {
   LetterImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.letterd);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To play a music in app, put the mp3 file inside the asset folder and load that music on media player from that location.

```
MediaPlayer m;



public void play() {
    try {
        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("A.mp3");
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```